# Linear transformation of a polyhedron

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

Is there a simple proof that shows:

1. Linear transformation of a $\mathcal{H}$-polyhedron (i.e. the intersection of
   finitely many closed half-spaces) is a $\mathcal{H}$-polyhedron.
2. Minkowski sum of two $\mathcal{H}$-polyhedrons is a $\mathcal{H}$-polyhedron.

I know a proof of (1.) based on Fourier-Motzkin elimination. and, I know (2.) is a simple consequence of (1.).

Every different approach is appreciated.

Comment: Why would anybody need Fourier-Motzkin elimination to prove (1)? It is immediate from the definition.

Comment: I might be missing something obvious, but I'm not convinced that 1. is immediate from the definition. That the image of a polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ under the projection map $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ to the first $n$ coordinates is again a polyhedron was apparently not considered too trivial to bother proving in Tame Topology and O-minimal Structures by van den Dries (see pp. 26-27). (The general result follows from this without too much pain.)

Comment: In fact, Fourier-Motzkin elimination looks, on the face of it, highly relevant to me, as this seems to be closely connected with quantifier-elimination for the theory of ordered vector spaces over an ordered field. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%E2%80%93Motzkin_elimination

Comment: @ToddTrimble: Todd, the definition that I had in mind is that a convex polytope $P$ is the convex hull of a finite set $V$. Now, if $L: R^n\to R^n$ is a linear map, then $L(P)$ is the convex hull of $L(V)$. (You can see this for instance by interpreting $P$ as a set of convex linear combinations of elements of $V$.) My guess is that van den Dries wanted to illustrate the quantifier elimination in a simple example. Or maybe the point is proving everything without first establishing equivalent characterizations of convex polyhedra.

Comment: @Misha: As I have mentioned in question, I consider a polyhedron as the intersection of finitely many closed half-spaces. A polyhedron is nit necessarily bounded.

Comment: @Misha Thanks. I was just about to remark as Mahdi did, although you might have an easy workaround to handle the noncompact case (do you?). But I think Mahdi's question is legitimate, since he asks for a *simple* proof that presumably works from first principles, i.e., from the definition he gives of polyhedron. My own feeling is that the question should be honored.

Comment: @Misha: As Todd mentioned, Fourier-Motzkin elimination uses to show that the projection of a polyhedron to some of coordinates is also a polyhedron.

Comment: @Todd: Yes, I do: Noncompact convex polyhedra are limits of sequences of compact ones, with the number of vertices bounded above.

Comment: @Misha It would be great to see such an argument fleshed out, just to dispel any worry that there's handwaving involved here. Would you consider writing up your thoughts as an answer? While I feel somewhat confident that Fourier-Motzkin is not to be dismissed lightly, any alternative insights you have would be appreciated. (Are there generalized linear program formulations that translate unbounded problems into bounded ones? Perhaps this paper is relevant: http://lara.epfl.ch/w/_media/projects:practical_issues_on_projection_of_convex_sets.pdf, especially in sections 4 and 5.)

Comment: Should "polyhedron" really be "convex polyhedron"?

Comment: Could someone explain why (1) is difficult? Doesn't a linear map map half-spaces to half-spaces and the intersection of a finite number of half-spaces into the intersection of the images of the half spaces?

Comment: @DeaneYang Yes, convex polyhedra are implied in the post (intersection of finitely many closed half-spaces). The trouble with your argument is that the taking of images does not preserve intersections.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Thanks for your useful references. Although Fourier_Motzkin elimination is very simple and elementary approach, but I am very curious to know is there any other approach?

Comment: What's wrong with the following? (Probably very close to what @Misha had in mind.) View a (not necessarily bounded) polytope as $\text{Conv}(\{u_i\}_{1 \le i \le k})+\text{Cone}(\{v_i\}_{1 \le i \le m})$ where $\text{Cone}(\{v_i\}_{1 \le i \le m}) = \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^m t_i v_i, \, t_i \ge 0 \right\}$. 
Now, if $L \in \text{End}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $L(P) = \text{Conv}(\{L(u_i)\}_{1 \le i \le k})+\text{Cone}(\{L(v_i)\}_{1 \le i \le m})$, which yields (1) (and so (2)).

Comment: @Danielm3 : This is neat (more elegant obviously than my pedestrian effort), but of course one could now ask for a "simple" proof of the fact that sets with these representations are exactly the polyhedrons as defined by the OP.

Comment: @Danielm3 That would be nice. I don't know if the following passage from my previous reference implies a possible obstruction (p. 304): "In the case of a polytope (bounded polyhedral set) one could use algorithms from computational geometry [3]. That is, first generate the set of extreme points of the polytope, project this set, eliminate the redundant projections and finally construct the convex hull of the remaining points. A natural generalization of this method to the unbounded case, however, leads to a far more complex algorithm (see [6]). (cont.)

Comment: "This is due to the fact that, in general, an unbounded polyhedral set cannot be fully described as the convex hull of its low-dimension faces such as extreme points and extreme rays whose projections are easy to compute." (end of quote) I'd be delighted if your idea works, but it would be good to have the details nailed down.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: I found this after some googling: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CFoQFjAI&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fftp.cis.upenn.edu%2Fpub%2Fcis610%2Fpublic_html%2Fconvex45.pdf&ei=s7iwU83bMJawyAS6soH4Dw&usg=AFQjCNGx8_2T9UdXGxBPK_Zn7dsxuDVNeg&bvm=bv.69837884,d.aWw This discusses the facts used by Daniel, but it seems to involve machinery.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Ah, good; thanks. The paper I just quoted also seems to invoke duals to reduce the unbounded case to the bounded one. But I have not studied this. (However, it looks as though a picture is emerging that might provide a truly alternative response for the OP.)

Comment: Indeed, 'dualization' (polar reciprocation) provides a geometric proof of the equivalence, albeit a somewhat involved one. Off the top of my head, I think Stoer and Witzgall present that approach in their book on "Convexity and optimization" but I do not have it handy to check at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Fourier-Motzkin, so I don't know how different the following argument is from what one usually does, but it's direct and elementary (and constructive, it in principle produces the new constraints from the old ones).

The claim *is* trivial if $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is invertible, and a general $A$ can be written as $A=PB$, with $B$ invertible and $P$ a projection, so we can focus on projections. We can in fact also assume that $P$ is a projection on a codimension $1$ subspace, say $P(y+\alpha e)=y$, for $y\perp e$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb R$. Suppose the polyhedron $Q$ is defined by the constraints $x\cdot n_j\le c_j$. We are then interested in
$$
S=P(Q)=\{ y\in\{e\}^{\perp} : y\cdot n_j \le c_j + d_j\alpha \:\textrm{ for some }\alpha\in\mathbb R \textrm{ and }j=1,\ldots, N \} 
$$
(the same $\alpha$ for all $j$ of course).
We can further assume that $d_j=0$ or $\pm 1$. Call a constraint zero, positive, or negative according to the sign of $d_j$. The zero constraints are already of the desired type and can be ignored. The case of only positive (or only negative) constraints is trivial ($S=\{e\}^{\perp}$ in both cases). In the remaining case, I claim that $y\in S$ precisely if
$$
y\cdot (n_k^+ + n_j^-) \le c_k^+ + c_j^-\quad\quad\quad (1)
$$
for all choices of pairs $(k,j)$ of one positive and one negative condition. Indeed, we can rewrite (1) as
$$
y\cdot n_k^+ \le c_k^+ + \min (c_j^--y\cdot n_j^-) ,
$$
and then observe that the largest $\alpha$ that satisfies all negative constraints for a given $y$ is $\alpha=\min (c_j^--y\cdot n_j^-)$. It is now clear that (1) is equivalent to $y\in S$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your Approach is similar to Fourier-Motzkin elimination.

Comment: For clarification your answer, Please says that $S$ is the projection of the polyhedron and defines theses notations: $n_j$, $c_j$ in your answer.

Comment: @Mahdi: Yes, $S$ is $P(Q)$, where $Q$ is the original polyhedron, defined by the constraints $x\cdot n_j\le c_j$. I'll edit.

Comment: I think that for compatibiliy of the dimensions of $y$ and $n_j$, it is better to write $y\in\{e\}^\perp$ instead of $y\in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ in definition of $S$.

Comment: Are you definition $P(Q)$ in the way you write there of you are trying to prove $P(Q)$ has that form? Moreover, why the same $\alpha$ for all $j$? Thank you!

Comment: Moreover, how you define $n_k^+$ and $c_k^+$?